# Which JQuery Tab Widget offers an onload event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, onload-event

Which tabstrip widget has a working onload event hook, so I can run some code (load tab contents) whenever a tab is opened?

JQuery UI tabs has an ["activate" event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate), but it's not triggered when the page is loaded, so opening URL#tabs-2 will show an empty second tab. There is a ["create" event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create), which is triggered when the page is loaded, but not when a tab is clicked, which leads to duplicate code (same callback in both events).
So far I've only found the [obvious workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17446803/664132) to put that code in a separate function loadTabstrip1Tab(index)/loadTabstrip2Tab(index)/... which is called in both events.
According to a [bug report (activate event not fired for first tab when created)](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8735), the lack of such an event seems to be a design decision.
There's probably a simple solution, but I can't seem to figure it out.
(Re-)[Activating the currently active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583129/664132) does nothing.

**Is there a fix for this widget?**

**Can someone recommend another tab widget which offers such a tab activation event hook?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found something for JQuery UI Tabs. The "show" option is not an event but it looks like it does what I'd expect the "activate" event to do:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    show: function( e,ui )
    {
        alert("tab " + ui.panel.id + " activated");
    }
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle demo (works with JQuery 1.9 + JQuery UI 1.9)](http://jsfiddle.net/r46YT/118/).

So I guess this turns the first question into "is this a good/bad solution"...